# HEROKU use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator

Tags: java, git, maven, heroku, jakarta-ee

I trying to make a deploy of my app builded in Java EE platform. When i run the command `git push heroku master`, at the finish of the deploy, many errors are   generated.

The principal exception is: `use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator`.

Someone have an idea about this error? Bellow is more messages of error.
Thank you if you can help me.

```
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run 
Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full 
debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible 
solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1]                         
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the 
issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: 
https://help.heroku.com/
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to wiidas-jee.
```

Comment: From [Oracle's documentation of `javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html): `javac -source 1.7` (or whatever source version you need)

Comment: Hi @Turing85 . But my compiler environment is 1.8. See bellow:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_162"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)
`

Comment: Yeah. Specify the source compatibility in your pom.xml (please don't ask me how - I do not use maven). This way, you can be sure that your source code is always compiled with the specified source compatibility. The problem is not at your local site, but on herokus end (the remote compile fails).

Comment: You must configure the maven-compiler-plugin.

Comment: @Turing85 and Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. Thank you for help me! After read more about how to setup Maven in Heroku, I found the solution! Adding the xml tags of the response(with some modifications more) of the codefinger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following plugin and configuration to your `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then run:

```
$ git add pom.xml
$ git commit -m "pom.xml"
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: Hi @codefinger! Your response was very important to my solution. After paste this tag's, make the commit and push, the build did not work. But, I searched  the exception generated and I changed the version of the maven to 3.8.2. And after this, he build worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: remote:        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
 remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------ 
        remote:        [INFO] Total time: 02:11 min
 remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2018-04-19T13:45:48+00:00
 remote:        [INFO] Final Memory: 38M/402M
 remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------